# how to get vscode to use my custom loader for intellisense & linting

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I have a very odd custom loader for node.js. I run it by using

```
node --loader ./custom-loader.mjs boot
```

it breaks a lot of rules about how module loading works, taking strings that arent paths at all, for academic and esoteric reasons. However, when run, it works. What I'd like to do, is have a way to tell vscode about my loader, so it will stop complaining that my import paths are invalid. The question is two parts:

1. How can i configure the linting, so that it knows my paths are valid?
2. Is it possible to (without getting into configuring a custom extension) configure intellisense to understand my loader.